# Orient Images in a Circle D3/JS

Tags: javascript, image, orientation, d3.js, geometry

I have 5 images that I am appending to a div that I want to be oriented in a circle.  Here is a snipit of the code which affixes 5 images to the div of interest:

```
diseases = ['d1', 'd2', 'd3']

images = d3.select('#welcome-container').selectAll('svg')
    .data(diseases).enter()
    .append('img')
    .attr('src', function(d) {return 'images/' + d + '_icon.png'})
    .attr('class', 'disease_icon')
    .attr('value', function(d) {return d})
```

The result is the images arranged in line block with a given height/width as a result of the class.  Is there something I can do to the .css or to this part of the JS that will orient them in a circle?  Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no CSS that will do this for you automatically. Aligning the images manually is not too hard though -- you can translate the individual image according to its index, e.g.

```
.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
  return "translate(" + (Math.cos(2*Math.PI/diseases.length*i)*radius) +
         "," + (Math.sin(2*Math.PI/diseases.length*i)*radius) + ")";
})
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the code. My svg elements now have a property "transform=translate(100,50)", but the svgs are in the same location on the page.  Is there something that I'm missing to actually move them?  Thanks,

Comment: Ah, I slightly misread your example -- if you're using individual SVGs, you can't use the transform attribute. The easiest way is probably to put the `<img>`s in `<div>`s and use CSS to move them. The principle is the same though, only instead of "translate(...)", you would generate something like "left: ...; bottom: ...;".

Comment: Thanks a lot -- I've gotten it to work by appending img elements to an svg.  Only issue is, the equation above results in about a half circle for 5 images.  Could you possible update the equation to render a full circle(ish)?  My geometry skill are not that up to par.  Thanks a bunch,

Comment: Apparently my geometry skills are a bit rusty as well :) I've updated the answer -- Math.PI should be 2*Math.PI.

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thanks so much.